# How to convert single sheet in XLS to PDF using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, pdf

I have working code that will convert an xls to pdf, however, the code converts the whole workbook and I really just need to select a single sheet out of the workbook, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The code I currently use is:

```
Dim fileName As String = "filepath\filename"
Dim xlsApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
xlsApp.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xlsBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim paramExportFormat As XlFixedFormatType = XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF
Dim paramExportQuality As XlFixedFormatQuality = XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard
Dim paramOpenAfterPublish As Boolean = False
Dim paramIncludeDocProps As Boolean = True
Dim paramIgnorePrintAreas As Boolean = True
Dim paramFromPage As Object = Type.Missing
Dim paramToPage As Object = Type.Missing
xlsBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName & ".xls", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
xlsBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFormat, fileName & ".pdf", paramExportQuality, paramIncludeDocProps, paramIgnorePrintAreas, paramFromPage, paramToPage, paramOpenAfterPublish)
xlsBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
xlsApp.Quit()
```

Where in the code do I need to specify the sheet in the workbook? Note that I will need to make it so that depending on an option fed into the app, the sheet will change, though I don't think that should make a difference, but I thought I'd mention it either way.

Comment: Can you use the `paramFromPage`, `paramToPage` parameters?

Comment: I don't know, but I will certainly try, not sure that affects the actual sheet in a workbook though.

Comment: If it's always printing the entire workbook, and the sheet that you want is on a particular page, and the workbook size never changes, you ought to be able to just specify the page you want printed (a lot of assumptions, I know).

Comment: That did work, I just changed them to Integer and specified both for page 1 and it only converted the first worksheet (first page).

Comment: I know it's an old question but you don't happen to remember how you specified the sheet do you?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [ExportAsFixedFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y916) method

```
Private Sub SaveWorksheetAsPDF()
    Dim mySheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet = xlsBook(0)

    mySheet.ExportAsFixedFormat( _
        Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, _
        "c:\myWorksheet", _
        Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, _
        True, _
        True, _
        1, _
        10, _
        False)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you look at the code I posted, I'm already using that method, but I created a workbook object and tried to export a single sheet, not a worksheet object for just the sheet I was interested in.

Comment: I don't see in your code that you export one sheet.  If you look at my code I have xlsBook(0) - which is first sheet.  In your code it might be second or third.  Try to use xlsBook(x) instead.